# Removing background from the sprite

Tags: background, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to "load" some 2d image [image] as a material for a mesh, (I know about spritemanager) but I'm unfortunately getting this sprite with it's white background. How can I "make it go"(the background)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is of a file type that supports transparency, open it up in image editing software (paint.net, photoshop, etc.) and delete the white or replace it with empty/transparent color.

Otherwise, look for an option in the unity documentation to set a specific color value as 'background' or 'transparent' so that that color will be ignored.

Comment: You have not used Unity, I assume?

Comment: @Jessy - No, I have not used Unity. I was just trying to give the best general advice I could.

Comment: Images with "transparency" work unreliably; I recommend an explicit alpha channel to avoid surprises.  (Transparency along with explicit alpha is also problematic.)  Photoshop's "maximize compatibility" is  necessary too.  None of the built in shaders can single out a color for opacity masking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add an alpha channel to your texture and save it in a format that supports alpha channel transparency.

Here is a quick tutorial on how to do this in GIMP:
[image: fig0]

Note that you can remove the selected background with the **Delete**-key.
In my case, I'm exporting the result as a PNG for alpha transparency support. You can do this from the export menu by renaming the file suffix to **.png**:

[image: fig1]

I use these settings to export my PNG:

[image: fig2]

Then, after importing the image into Unity, Make sure that in the texture's import settings the image's alpha source is set to **Input Texture Alpha** and that **Alpha is Transparency** tickbox is checked like so:

[image: fig3]

Finally, since you are using this on a mesh, you need to ensure that your mesh has a material applied that has it's render mode set to **Cutout**:

[image: fig4]

Hope this little guide helps.